# Apache still loads test page when the log says it has rewritten the request to a php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have configured an apache virtualhost to point localhost to /var/www/html/mysite/public which contains a htaccess file rewriting all request to handle.php in the same dir, I know the htaccess file works because syntax errors in it cause internal server errors to appear

But when I go to localhost/ I get the apache test page, I enabled `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3` to see what was going on and the log shows that it's trying to rewrite the request to handle.php but... not? What is going on here

handle.php just contains `die('test');` so I'd know if it actually used that file

```
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248162 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca71a60/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/mysite/public/ ->
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248270 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca71a60/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri ''
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248298 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca71a60/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/mysite/public/ ->
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248312 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca71a60/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^' to uri ''
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248362 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca71a60/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] pass through /var/www/html/mysite/public/
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248816 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/mysite/public/index.php -> index.php
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248840 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'index.php'
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248907 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'handle.php'
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248922 2018] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] add per-dir prefix: handle.php -> /var/www/html/mysite/public/handle.php
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248936 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/mysite/public/ with /
[Mon Dec 03 09:23:09.248949 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 183] mod_rewrite.c(482): [client snip:35984] snip - - [localhost/sid#55879ca14140][rid#55879ca77a90/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/mysite/public/] internal redirect with /handle.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because my apache was in a docker container and docker was preventing apache reading dirs that didn't exist, strace was extremely useful in debugging this. See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1295